# Sorting bibliography by appearance (sorting=none) with \nocite{*}

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, sorting

I know there are lots of similar questions, but I have problems with my particular code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[sorting=none,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references2.bib}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\nocite{*} 

\begin{document}

Hello \cite{a}. Goodbye \cite{b}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The references are sorted by order of appearance in the `.bib` file, and I want them to be sorted by order of citation in the text. What can I do? I tried `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` but it gives me error. The only solution I see is manually ordering the `.bib` file.

Comment: Don't issue `\nocite{*}` in the preamble, only issue it directly before `\printbibliography`.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to issue `\nocite{*}` as late as possible, otherwise the `\nocite`'d entries take precedence (according to their order in the `.bib` file because `sorting=none` can consider no other properties and needs some way to break ties) over the entries that are explicitly cited in the document. (Hopefully https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/a988fa1e3bfabf4efac5bb9af6fed2b69f1e055f makes that a bit clearer in the documentation.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=none, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{worman,
  author       = {Worman, Nancy},
  title        = {The Cast of Character},
  date         = 2002,
  publisher    = {University of Texas Press},
  location     = {Austin},
}
@book{nussbaum,
  author       = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title        = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  date         = 1978,
  publisher    = {Princeton University Press},
  location     = {Princeton},
}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  date         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Hello \cite{sigfridsson}.
Goodbye \cite{nussbaum}.

\printbibliography
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Hello [1]. Goodbye [2].]

Comment: hey, sorry why would you change the import instead of using \bibliographystyle{unsrt}   ? Is it not possible to use the latter ? Best,

Comment: @MarineGalantin I'm not quite sure I understand your question. The `filecontents` environment in this answer is only there to generate a `.bib` file on the fly and make it self-contained. In a real-world document you would not have the `\usepackage{filecontents} \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}...\end{filecontents}` block, instead you would generate the `.bib` either manually or via a bibliography manager such as JabRef or Zotero. `\bibliographystyle` is a BibTeX command that can not be used together with `biblatex` (so it can't be used with the code shown in the question).

Comment: oh ! I understand ! That's why it wasn't working, thank you hahah

Comment: on a different subject how do you write code text in a comment please ? It might be useful for readibility in the future.

Comment: @MarineGalantin With backticks `\``, you say `this is text \`this is code\` text again`.